# Split classes in corine land cover raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have a raster with 44 classes of land cover. 
How can I split this raster in 44 rasters, each one with one class of land cover?

I am working with ArcGIS 10.2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need Spatial Analyst extension to be active.

In the ArcToolbox locate "Extract by attributes" under "Spatial Analyst Tool -> Extraction".

Fill the mask with:

- the input raster (Corine Land Cover full dataset)
- where clause: you need to fill an SQL statement to extract the data. Help provided "The expression follows the general form of an SQL expression. It can be entered directly into the Where clause, for example, "VALUE" > 100. "
- the output raster: locate the folder and fill in with the name of the output raster.

In your case, the SQL statement will be something like "VALUE" = 1, "VALUE" = 2, depending on the values stored in your raster dataset.

Since you have 44 classes, you can use the "Batch processing" to do that:

- locate "Extract by attributes" in the ArcToolbox
- right click and choose "Batch"
- fill in with the 44 classes and run